# What causes a .net program to look for files in System32 or SysWOW64?

Tags: .net, dll

I have code that is dependent on a third parties dll that normally is installed in the system folder. When I run some code referencing this dll it works fine as it picks it up from either System32 or SysWOW64 depending on the bit version of the process. But with some other code it works only if the dll is in the bin folder, if not then file not found exception is thrown.

What causes a .net program to look for files in System32 or SysWOW64 respectively?

Answer (score 3):

"Third party DLLs" is vague, but it fits the bill if they are unmanaged DLLs.  Usually referenced by [DllImport] directives in the program.  The CLR asks Windows to load the DLL, it needs to find the DLL and looks in just a few places for the file.  The directory where the EXE is stored is first, the Windows system directory is next, the directories listed by the PATH environment variable are next.  Since the search always includes the Windows system directory, it tends to be ab/used to store those DLLs.

If the DLLs are .NET assemblies then this won't work, the CLR never looks in the operating system directory or the PATH directories for the file.  It looks in the GAC first, the directory that stores the EXE next.  With an option to look in a subdirectory of the EXE directory if you use the `<probing>` element in the app.exe.config file.  So that's the likely reason in your case.

*Always* store DLLs in the same directory as the EXE, that avoids lots of trouble.  The Windows system directory is not a good place, DLL Hell is a very unpleasant problem.

Comment: Thanks, sorry forgot to mention that the dll's were indeed unmanaged. And also as you assumed referenced by [DllImport]. So if I understand you correctly, windows should have loaded the dll from the system directory and I shouldn't have seen this error?

Comment: I still have no idea whatsoever what "some other code" might mean.  And what error?  I can only answer the "What causes a .net program to look for files in System32" question.

Comment: "some code" and "some other code" = managed c# code, in two different projects. The error = FileNotFound exception, casued by the unmanaged dll not being found.